# Trying to split a string into parts

Tags: c

I got 2 arrays :

```
data[256] = "1@2@3@4@5"
question[256][256];
```

I need to split the number before the `@` into an array..
for example :

```
question[0][] = 1
question[1][] = 2
question[2][] = 3
question[3][] = 4
question[4][] = 5
```

It doesnt metter if I have the `@` in, or not.

This is what I wrote :

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
 data = "1@2@3@4@5";

 for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(data) ; i++)
 {
     for (j ; data[j] != '@' ; j++)
     {
         question[i][j] = data[j];
     }
     j++
 }

 printf ("%s\n", question);
```

The problem is, it works untill the first `@`, and then stops.
It only put the first `@` into question, and then stops.
(basiclly I'm supposed to get the same output for printing both data, and question).

Comment: `question` is not a string, so you can't printf it with `%s`.

Comment: Since it's homework, I guess you can't be using built in functions like `strchr` or similar?

Comment: Also, is there anything in `question` before you start, or have you cleared out its contents?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The question doesn't mention any restrictions, and there's `strlen` in the example code.

Comment: JoachimPileborg   I can use string functions..
MrLister Question is empty...
LihO It's a code inside a function, but the problem is in the code I've posted above, not others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems.

First, `printf` only prints the string until the first terminating zero character (`'\0'`), which happens after the first "part" in `question` (even though there are other parts.  Instead, you will need to print all:

```
for (i=0; i<255; ++i) {
  printf("%s\n", question[i]);
}
```

Make sure you null-terminate (`'\0'`) the rows of `question` before, so you don't print garbage for uninitialized rows.  or just maintain the index of the last-good row and iterate until that

Also, the loop

```
for(j; data[j]!='@', j++)
```

will stop at the first `'@'`, and all consequent iterations of the outside loop will evaluate the same `j` (which is the index of `'@'`, so the loop is skipped in further iterations.  You will need to advance `j` after the inner loop

you will also need to maintain a last-`j` position after the last `'@'` to be able to calculate the position of `j` from the last `'@'`, so you can index into `question[i]` properly.  set `lastj` to the value of `j` after is extra advancement suggested in the previous paragraph.  Also, the second index of `question` should be `j-lastj` from now on.

Yet another thing about the inner loop: as it is, it will advance past the string in `data` after the last `'@'`, so you will have to check for noll-termination as well.

Also, make sure you null-terminate the strings in `question`, otherwise `printf` will produce garbage (and possibly seg-fault when reaching memory not allocated to your progam).  just write

```
question[i][j-lastj] = '\0';
```

after the inner loop.  (`j` will have pointed after the last written index at the end of the inner loop)

Yet one more thing: do not iterate `i` until the length of `data` as you will not need to touch that many elements (and likely will overindex `data` in the inner loop).  Use a `while` loop instead, incrementing `i` only until you have covered `data` with `j` in the inner loop

*Note*: look up [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to make the tokenization easier on your part

Comment: I've did all u said, though the printf gives me insted of numbers, weird symbols... I've tried %c and %s, both print me symbols...

Comment: @AmitM9S6 - first of all, you haven't cleared `question` first.  Also, (I missed this in my post) you need to maintain the last position of `j` that points after the `'@'`, so you can put the character in the right place in `question`.  See a working code here: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/j6rcv)

Comment: Yes, because that code prints the whole `question` array.  If you only need the non-empty parts, print only up to `i` (use a different loop variable)

Comment: @the last loop goes until 256, which is the whole range of the `question` array.  Instead your loop should be something like this: `int k; for (k=0; k<i+1; ++k) {...}` as `i` still holds the last valid index of `question`

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `strchr` to get the location of the next `'@'`.

The algorithm is something like this: You get the position of the next `'@'`, and if there is none found then set `next` to the end of the string. Then copy from the current `beginning` of the string to `next` position into where you want it. Remember to terminate the copied string! Set the `beginning` of the string to one beyond `next`. Repeat until `beginning` is beyond the end of the data.

**Edit:** Code for my solution:

```
char *beg = data;
char *end = data + strlen(data);  /* Points to one beyond the end of 'data' */

for (int i = 0; beg < end; i++)
{
    char *next = strchr(beg, '@');  /* Find next '@' */
    if (next == NULL)
        break;  /* No more '@' */

    memcpy(question[i], beg, next - beg);  /* Copy to array */
    question[i][next - beg] = '\0';  /* Remember to terminate string */

    beg = next + 1;  /* Point to next possible number */
}
```

Note: Not tested. Might be one of with the copying, might have to be `next - beg - 1`. (Even after 25 years of C-programming, I always seem to get that wrong on the first try... :) )

Comment: @AmitM9S6 No linked list, just copy the string (using either `strncpy` or `memcpy`) into your array, and increase the index.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to do this.  Use `strtok` to tokenize the string by `"@"`, and then use `strcpy` to copy the tokenized strings into your `question` array.  For example (not tested):

```
char *pcur = data;
int i = 0;

do
{
  if ((pcur = strtok(pcur, "@")) != NULL)
  {
    strcpy(question[i], pcur++);
    printf ("%s\r\n", question[i++]);
  }
}
while (pcur != NULL);
```

As shown in the above example, incrementing `i` moves the `question` array index to the next position, and incrementing `pcur` moves the tokenized string pointer past the nulled token for the next iteration through the loop.

See also:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663.aspx

Comment: That `if` statement may give warnings in some compilers, better use something like `if ((pcur = strtok(pcur, "@")) != NULL)`